# Can't send data as hidden field in form from html to controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my Spring boot 2 project:

Model:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;
```

Here my template - **category.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${appName}">Category template title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/public/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="#" th:object="${category}" th:action="@{/category}">
        <h3>Category</h3>
        <input type="hidden" id="id" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <input type="hidden" placeholder="created" id="created" th:field="*{created}"/>
        <textarea placeholder="Description of the category" rows="5" id="description"
                  th:field="*{description}"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    <div class="result_message" th:if="${submitted}">
        <h3>Your category has been submitted.</h3>
        <p>Find all categories <a href="/categories">here</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here result generated html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="/public/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="/category"><input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="b578aef2-491c-4e1a-a3a5-72cb679c6222"/>
        <h3>Category</h3>
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="2"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" name="name" value="Electronics"/>
        <input type="hidden" placeholder="created" id="created" name="created" value="2020-01-08 13:46:39.787"/>
        <textarea placeholder="Description of the category" rows="5" id="description" name="description">Electronics&#39;s description</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here controller:

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CategoryController.class);

    // If class has only one constructore then @Autowired wiil execute automatically
    public CategoryController(CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        createStubCategoryList();
    }

    @GetMapping("/categories")
    public String getCategories(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("categoryList", categoryRepository.findAll());
        return "categories";
    }

    @RequestMapping("category/edit/{id}")
    public String editCategory(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        Optional<Category> category = categoryRepository.findById(id);
        logger.info("find_category = " + category);
        model.addAttribute("category", category);
        return "category";
    }

    @RequestMapping("category/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteCategory(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        categoryRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "redirect:/categories";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/category")
    public String submitCategory(Category category, Model model) {
        category.setUpdated(new Date());
        logger.info("updateCategory = " + category);
        model.addAttribute("submitted", true);
        model.addAttribute("category", category);
        categoryRepository.save(category);
        return "category";
    }
```

But when I try to click submit button on `/category` page I get error:

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Wed Jan 08 13:52:21 EET 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='category'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'category' on field 'created': rejected value [2020-01-08 13:46:39.787]; codes [typeMismatch.category.created,typeMismatch.created,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [category.created,created]; arguments []; default message [created]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'created'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull java.util.Date] for value '2020-01-08 13:46:39.787'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
```

Comment: How I see the problem is in date format. May be `@DateTimeFormat` annotation in the model class could help?

Comment: I think your date format  are not same.
Try with this one: `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")private Date created;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@DateTimeFormat` annotation to Date fields in your entity. For example:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
private Date created;
```